# Optimize splitting fixed length segments

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I can get an infinite supply of segments only of length 'n'. I need to cut these segments into many smaller sub-segments of lengths between '1' and 'n - 1'. After cutting the larger 'n' length segments into smaller ones, there will inevitably be leftover "waste" that is shorter than any desired sub-segment.

Is there an efficient algorithm that can output the optimal cuts that provides minimal waste? Another way to ask this: what cuts require the minimal number of 'n' length segments split into the desired sub-segments? We can assume the list of desired sub-segments is sorted.

A greedy algorithm (take the longest possible next segment) is efficient, but usually produces lots of waste. A brute force will not work as the number of cuts could be too large to efficiently calculate. Since it's an optimization question, I considered constructing a linear program, but was unsuccessful.

A simple example (n = initial segment length, s = list of desired sub-segments):

```
n = 100
s = 50, 30, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21

Greedy yields:
1: 50, 30, waste 20
2: 21, 21, 21, 21, waste 16
3: 21, waste 79
Total waste: 115

Optimal should yield:
1: 50, 21, 21, waste 8
2: 30, 21, 21, 21, waste 7
Total waste: 15
```

Comment: Do you know all the segments you need to make ahead of time or do orders arrive sequentially?

Comment: All segments lengths are known ahead of time before starting the first cut.

Comment: How many segments comprise a typical problem instance?

Comment: 10's of thousands is typical.

Answer (score 0):

I have formulated the above problem as a mathematical optimization problem, and have expressed it in Google-ortool's CP-SAT solver (python API).
For the problem, I get the optimal solution as

```
100 ==> 21, 21, 21, 30
100 ==> 21, 21, 50
```

The program should scale well for larger problem instances. Allocate more VCPUs to the solver and control the upper bound of number of larger segments (100) that you have to begin with (this will limit the number of decision variables that will get created)

code listing :

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp

n = 100
s = [50, 30, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21]
s.sort()

s_set = sorted(set(s))
lst = []
for i in s_set:
    repeats = s.count(i)
    for j in range(repeats):
        lst.append(str(i) + "_" + str(j+1))

# with lst we differentiate between 21's to give
# them a separate identity, so that we can distinguish between
# them. This is for the program, but obviously at the end of
# the day they are the same.

map_lst_to_s = {k: v for k,v in zip(lst, s)}

supply_n = 10 # arbitarily put an upper bound on availability

model = cp.CpModel()

# decision variable : assign a sub-segment (say 50, 30 .. ) to the larger segment (100)
dv_assign = {}
for i in range(supply_n):
    for j in lst:
        dv_assign[(i, j)] = model.NewBoolVar("")

# constraint : length of all assigned sub-segments (to a larger segment) cannot exceed
# the length of the larger segment
for i in range(supply_n):
    model.Add(sum(dv_assign[(i, j)] * map_lst_to_s[j] for j in lst) <= n)

# constraint : one sub-segment can't be assigned to more than 1 distinct larger segment
# e.g. 50 can't be assigned to 2 distinct 100 segments
for j in lst:
    model.Add(sum(dv_assign[(i, j)] for i in range(supply_n)) == 1)
    
# how much wastage happened in a segment
wastage_per_segment = {}
for i in range(supply_n):
    wastage_per_segment[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, n, "")
    model.Add(wastage_per_segment[i] == n - sum(dv_assign[(i, j)] * map_lst_to_s[j] for j in lst))

# remember, we have surplus supply of larger segments (100) to start with
# now, larger segments that are completely un-used will not 
# contribute towards wastage
was_segment_used = {}
wastage_per_segment_if_segment_used = {}
for i in range(supply_n):
    was_segment_used[i] = model.NewBoolVar("")
    wastage_per_segment_if_segment_used[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, n, "")
    model.AddMaxEquality(was_segment_used[i], [dv_assign[(i, j)] for j in lst])
    model.AddMultiplicationEquality(wastage_per_segment_if_segment_used[i], [was_segment_used[i], wastage_per_segment[i]])

total_wastage = model.NewIntVar(0, n * supply_n, "")
model.Add(total_wastage == sum(wastage_per_segment_if_segment_used[i] for i in range(supply_n)))

model.Minimize(total_wastage)

solver.ObjectiveValue()

solver = cp.CpSolver()

solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8  # use 8 VCPUs for larger problem instances
# solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True  # uncomment to print solver logs
# solver.log_callback = print
solver.Solve(model) 

# inspect decision variable values

# how much total wastage happened per larger segment (100)
# that was used
for i in range(supply_n):
    if solver.Value(wastage_per_segment_if_segment_used[i]) > 0:
        print(solver.Value(wastage_per_segment_if_segment_used[i]))

# which smaller segment was assigned to the larger segment
for i in range(supply_n):
    if solver.Value(was_segment_used[i]) > 0:
        print(str(100) + " ==> " + 
            ", ".join([str(solver.Value(dv_assign[(i, j)]) * map_lst_to_s[j]) for j in lst if solver.Value(dv_assign[(i, j)]) > 0]))
```